# What were the steps in the linearization of the following equation?

Tags: logarithms, linearization

I'm verifying a linear form of an equation, i.e.

[image]

I can't find how the equation 6 leads to the equation 7

[image]

Comment: Looks wrong to me.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you mean that the paper author did a wrong linearization?

Answer (score 1):

It must be a misprint. I assume the model must be:
$$q_e=q_Dexp\left(-B_D\left[RT\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{C_e}\right)^2\right]\right).$$

Comment: The model is $q_{e}=q_{D}\exp{\left( -B_{D}\varepsilon^{2} \right) }$ with $\varepsilon=RT\ln\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{C_{e}}\right) $. This exact model is in every literature that I consulted